# Use output of one command as replacement text in sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a .env file with a bunch of key-value pairs like so:

```
NAME=John Doe
CITY=Timbuctoo
CSS=<some value>
PORT=3000
```

It is the third line I'm trying to change programmatically.  is a dynamically-generated md5 hash and each time I run the command, it needs to be replaced by a new hash. This is how I'm generating the hash:

```
$ date +%s | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

And I wish to use the output of the above command as the replacement text when using sed. But can't figure out how to make it work. The following is the solution I have so far which is far from complete:

```
$ date +%s | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sed -i.bak 's/^\(CSS=\).*/replacement/' ~/nano/.env
```

What should put in place of "replacement" to ensure the original value gets replaced by the value returned by `cut`?

Comment: MD5 sums are used to represent large chunks of data with a relatively small value. Why are you using one in place of a 10-byte value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `xargs` with `I` and a place-holder `{}` to store the value `stdin` and pass it over to `sed` as

```
date +%s | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs -I {} sed -i.bak 's/^\(CSS=\).*/CSS={}/' file
```

But I would wisely *avoid*  introducing another pipe-line and would use a separated command for `sed`

```
newHash=$(date +%s | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f 1); sed -i.bak "s/^\(CSS=\).*/CSS=${newHash}/" file
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use

```
sed -i.bak "s/^\(CSS=\).*/$(date +%s | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f 1)/" ~/nano/.env
```

The important thing is to use `"` instead of `'` so that bash substitutes the subshell command `$(...)`.